# Autohotkey runs Excel VBA macro but changes are not applied

Tags: vba, excel, autohotkey

I have an Excel file, say `Plano.xlsx` and I am trying to run a VBA macro script on it using Autohotkey following the instructions stated [here](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/80602-run-excel-vba-macro-via-ahk-l-and-com/).
I don't want the Excel to be visible during this process. The VBA code is supposed to enter the value 99 in the cell C1 at the first sheet. 
After hours of trial and error, the Autohotkey script runs smoothly without errors i.e. it opens an Excel process in the background supposedly 
editing the Excel file and then exits. The problem is that the Excel file does not change at all. The VBA code works fine if I paste it manually 
in a new VBA module in Excel without using Autohotkey.

Here is the code:

```
#SingleInstance force

#Include Acc.ahk

VBcode=
(
Sub myFunction()
    Worksheets(1).Select
    Worksheets(1).Range("C1").Select
    Selection.Value = 99
End Sub
)

Excel_Run("myFunction")

Excel_Run(sFunction){
    FilePath = C:\Users\KostasK\Desktop\Plano.xlsx
    oExcel := ComObjCreate("Excel.Application")
    Excel_ImportCode(VBcode)
    oWorkbook := oExcel.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    Excel_Get().Run(sFunction)
    oWorkbook.Save
    oExcel.Quit
}

Excel_ImportCode(VBcode){
    if fileexist(A_ScriptDir . "\tempvbcode.txt")
        FileDelete, %A_ScriptDir%\tempvbcode.txt

    FileAppend, %VBcode%, %A_ScriptDir%\tempvbcode.txt

    Excel_Get().ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
        .VBComponents.Import(A_ScriptDir . "\tempvbcode.txt")
}

Excel_Get(WinTitle="ahk_class XLMAIN") {    ; by Sean and Jethrow, minor modification by Learning one
    ControlGet, hwnd, hwnd, , Excel71, %WinTitle%
    if !hwnd
        return
    Window := Acc_ObjectFromWindow(hwnd, -16)
    Loop
        try
            Application := Window.Application
        catch
            ControlSend, Excel71, {esc}, %WinTitle%
    Until !!Application
    return Application
}
```

To get the Acc.ahk library that is included in the script please see [here](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/77303-acc-library-ahk-l-updated-09272012/). My Autohotkey version is v.1.1.23.05 and I use Excel 2013. I did not 
take a closer look on `Excel_Get()` function but I used it instead of `ComObjActive("Excel.Application")` because the latter produces errors. There 
is some useful info about that [here](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/77840-how-to-pass-com-object-pointer-to-a-script/#entry495039). Finally, please note that I have enabled the following options in Excel Trust Center: 
`Enable all macros (not recommended, potentially dangerous code can run)` and `Trust access to the VBA project object model`. Also, in Add-ins section 
in COM Add-ins nothing is checked (I don't know if that matters). Finally, I always run the script as administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished simply without VBA macro, while file being closed.

```
FilePath = C:\Users\KostasK\Desktop\Plano.xlsx
oExcel := ComObjGet(FilePath)
oExcel.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").VALUE := "99" ; you can put actual sheet name instead "sheet1"
oExcel.Save
oExcel.Quit
oExcel :=
```